# Загрузка изображений c помощью PIL. Python

Tags: python, numpy, pil, pillow

Мне нужно загрузить много небольших изображений. На каждую букву алфавита порядка 2000 изображений, каждое 145х145 (вес каждого около 400 байт).
Каждое изображение загружаю следующим образом:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(filepath).convert('L')
(width, height) = im.size
greyscale_map = list(im.getdata())
greyscale_map = np.array(greyscale_map)
greyscale_map = greyscale_map.reshape((height, width))
```

В итоге из 14 мб изображений, я получаю 14 гб объектов `.npy`.
Можно что-нибудь сделать с размером? Может как-то по  другому загружать? 
В дальнейшем эти данные нужно будет пропускать через нейронную сеть.

Comment: Вы можете выложить ссылки на несколько изображений, чтобы можно было протестировать код? Какие библитотеки вы планируете использовать для тренировки (обучения) моделей? Поддерживает ли данная библиотека `sparse matrix` (`csr_matrix`)?

Comment: Вместо сохранения изображений как непожатых numpy массивов в npy файлы на диске, вы можете использовать  форматы для изображений png, gif, djvu, jpeg, etc.

Comment: Как вход,  использую тип uint8.  Это помогло сократить размер почти в 8 раз.  Планирую использовать lasagne

Comment: Изображения типа mnist.  Только кроме цифр еще все буквы русского алфавита